# iPhone (iOS6) will not mount

Tags: mount, iphone

After plugging in the iPhone,

```
sudo lsusb
```

says

```
...
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc.
...
```

and

```
sudo dmesg
```

says

```
...
[ 4187.142844] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 4191.045639] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 4191.176600] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8
[ 4191.176605] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4191.176608] usb 3-1: Product: iPhone
[ 4191.176610] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 4191.176613] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1a4ea506902b302eddd656817e91d540010af6ac
[ 4191.176774] usb 3-1: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 8 microframes, ep desc says 10 microframes
[ 4191.176780] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 8 microframes, ep desc says 10 microframes
```

But,

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

says

```
Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048    610303    608256   297M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  610304 234440382 233830079 111.5G Microsoft basic data
...
Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  100665343  100663296    48G Linux swap
/dev/sdb2  100665344 1953522765 1852857422 883.5G Linux filesystem
```

and

```
sudo lsblk
```

says

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   297M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 111.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    48G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb2   8:18   0 883.5G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The phone is partially detected but not mounted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually traced this problem to the cable. I swapped it with the other apple cable I had (also original from an older iPhone) and it worked.

Note that the output of fdisk and lsusb were as above, but the phone was mounted in the file manager.

Comment: I had the same issue and swapping the cable solved it. Very strange behaviour !